# Should I use volatile with RDMA buffers?

Tags: rdma, infiniband

I am learning RDMA verbs in C (`libibverbs`).

One question I have is after having polled a Receive Work Completion with a Receive RDMA write with immediate (`IBV_WC_RECV_RDMA_WITH_IMM`), the compiler might not see that the content of the receiving buffer has changed. So, do we need to declare the receiving buffer `volatile`? AFAI, this is one usage of `volatile`: the content of the variable can be modified by an external source (here, RDMA hardware).

An example of code:

```c
void receive(volatile char* receiving_buffer, size_t size, ibv_cq *cq)
{
    ibv_wc wc;
    int n = 0;
    while(n == 0) n = ibv_poll_cq(cq, 1, &wc);

    assert(wc.status == IBV_WC_SUCCESS);
    assert(wc.opcode == IBV_WC_RDMA_WRITE && (wc.wc_flags & IBV_WC_WITH_IMM));

    // Prevent buffer overflow
    receiving_buffer[size - 1] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", receiving_buffer);    
}
```

Is qualifying `receiving_buffer` with `volatile` needed?

I guess the answer will be the same for RDMA write or RDMA send.

Comment: Volatile is rarely used with whole buffers, and used instead with flags for their management such as in an implementation of a mutex. Is there something that can be set to indicate the buffer is currently being worked or how much has been updated?

Comment: I am sending the whole buffer at once, so with only one RDMA write, therefore we know exactly what content changed (from `receiving_buffer` to `receiving_buffer + size`). I have added `size` in the question. Maybe using memory barriers (I don't know how to use them) will also work and be more efficient?

Comment: The reason one ends up with outdated data is that data changes.  Thus there must be something doing the changing.  If you can have that entity provide a summary(yes/no or N bytes done) of what it's doing (perhaps via a callback of sorts), then that number is what should be considered volatile.

Comment: But isn't it exactly what `ibv_poll_cq()` does? Like in the code in the question, when the `while()` loop will finish, we know that the content of the buffer *will* have changed. Since we know how much bytes have been written, we also know exactly which memory locations have changed (we can just assume the entire content of the buffer changed, or use `wc.byte_len` that provide this information, available for RDMA write with immediate).

Comment: If that is what the loop does, was there anything gained by an "immediate" feature?

Comment: Oh sorry, I have forgotten updating `n`. I have edited my question. The immediate flag permits to generation a Receive Completion Event (so that the event is notified and `n` is set to `1`), which is not the case without the immediate (no notification without it).

Comment: So to the best of my knowledge, you don't need to use volataile. But it is up to the programmer, to remember, there are [long] periods of time when the data is invalid and/or incomplete.

Comment: Further more:
So the 'volatile' is a keyword used to mark the compiler the value stored in the given var may have been changed by other thread, and thus the compiler shouldn't do excessive optimization.
in your case i think it would be best to use explicit rdma msgs for marking whether the data is available for read or write (so write_imm to mark the receiver is ready to read, and give back a send to mark ready to receive).